# How to pass service URL data to a function where it's called by controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise, angular-services

I am trying to fetch some data from an URL, store it in a variable and return it to my controller. But the problem is that the data from URL is processed after the variable has already been returned to the controller (which calls the function). I am calling the service URL in my **Service.js**
Here is how I am doing it:

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', []).service('myService', function($http, $q) {
    var gaugeData = {
        maxValue: 5000,
        animationSpeed: 100,
        val: 5000
    };

    console.log(gaugeData);

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('http://myurl').then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data.Tweets[3].FAVOURITE_COUNT);
        var gaugeData = {
            maxValue: 5000,
            animationSpeed: 100,
            val: data.data.Tweets[3].FAVOURITE_COUNT
        };
        deferred.resolve(gaugeData);
        console.log(gaugeData);
    });

    this.get = function() {
        deferred.promise.then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            gaugeData.val = data.val;
        });
        return gaugeData;
    };

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this.list = function() {
        return gaugeData;
    };

});
```

The controller expects data in the same form as `gaugeData` object, but since the `gaugeData` gets filled with service data after the value has already been returned, the controller shows no object (*undefined*). The Console looks like this:

```
    Object {maxValue: 5000, animationSpeed: 100, val: 5000}
    controllers.js:202 $…t.l.$…w.a.$…e.$$ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: Object…}   (console.log); from controller 
    app.js:15 TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxValue' of undefined (since an empty value is passed)
       1566
   services.js:137 Object {maxValue: 5000, animationSpeed: 100, val: 1566}
   services.js:144 Object {maxValue: 5000, animationSpeed: 100, val: 1566}
```

Clearly the control first enters the service and then while the URL is being processed, the control jumps to the control and takes an empty value and after this has happened the URL is processed and `gaugeData` gets filled with the values from the service URL. 
I tried doing this without promise and deferred. I simply used `$http.get(url).success(function(){code});`

How can I pass my URL data to a variable and pass it correctly to the controller at the right time?

Also here is my controller code snippet where I am calling the service function:

```
console.log($scope);
return $scope.gaugeHome ={
         gaugeData:
             myService.get(), .....
```

Comment: `this` inside a `then` is the window object, this is an error in strict mode - run your code in strict mode :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum — author actually does not have `this` inside `then`. Just had poor indenting (fixed now). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't wrap existing promises in new deferrals; that is an anti-pattern. `$http` already returns a promise, which you can modify by `return`ing new promises or values from `then` handlers.
2. You cannot return a sync value which is the result of an async operation. It's a fundamental contradiction in terms. If you need to return something that will eventually be set to a value, that's the whole point of a promise. Your service should return a promise, which your controller will then call `then` on.
3. Your `sleep` function is worrisome. It looks like you are using a busy loop in order to… do what? Hang the CPU for a period? Why? And why not just `$timeout`?

Here is a version of your service which A) fetches the resource one time, B) stores it in a promise, and C) lets consumers (controllers) ask for the promise. Controllers will then have to call `then` to decide what to do with the result.

If you wanted your service to be able to update the resource, you could wrap the promise generation in a function which runs the fetch again and returns a new promise. It's not entirely clear what your end goal is, however, so I didn't show that approach.

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', []).service('myService', function($http, $q) {

    var gaugePromise = $http.get('http://myurl').then(function(response) {
        var updatedGuageData = {
            maxValue: 5000,
            animationSpeed: 100,
            val: response.data.Tweets[3].FAVOURITE_COUNT
        };
        return updatedGuageData;
    });

    this.get = function() {
        return gaugePromise;
    };

});
```

Now, you *could* have the service cache the value as a synchronous object (along the lines of what you were attempting), and whenever you async get it, update the cache as a side effect (as you were doing). However, any time you did an asynchronous update, the only time you would know that it had succeeded (or failed) is by using a callback or promise handler, which makes the cached synchronous value kind of pointless — why not just use the results of the async directly? Much simpler.